# Помогите отсортировать массив на C

Tags: c, массивы, сортировка

не понимаю как отсортировать массив на С ,чтоб сначала шли элементы по возростанию , а потом нули

задается интервал от [n до n_n] , в котором числа остаются , в противном случае числа обнуляются ,

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
const int N=10;
int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b) {
return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}
int main()
{
    int a[N];
    int k,n,n_n,sum,i,j,temp;
    k=0;
    printf("vvedite nachalinoe i konechnoe znacenie intervala\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &n , &n_n);
    for ( i=0 ; i <N ; i++){
        printf("%d=", i+1 );
        scanf("%d" , &a[i]);
    }
    for (j=0 ; j<N ; j++){
        if(a[j] > k) k=a[j];
    }
    printf("maksimalinii polojelemmassiva=%d\n" , k);
    for (i=0 ;i<N ;i++){  
        sum = sum + a[i];
    }
    sum -= k ;
    printf ("summa massiva=%d\n", sum);
    for ( i=0; i<N; i++){ 
        if ( n > a[i] || a[i] > n_n){
            a[i]=0;
        } 
    }
qsort(a,N,sizeof(int),cmpfunc);
    for (j=0;j<N;j++){ 
        for (  i=0; i< N ; i++){ 
                    if (a[i]<a[i+1])
                    {
                        temp=a[i];
                        a[i]=a[i+1];
                        a[i+1]=temp;
                    }
        }
    }/*
            for(i=0;i<n_n-n;i++){ 
                if (a[i]>a[i+1]){
                    for (i=0; i <n_n-n;i++){
                        temp=a[i];
                        a[i]=a[i+1];
                        a[i+1]=temp;
                    }
                }
            }
*/

    printf("sorted massiv a =");
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        printf("%d ; ",a[j]);
    return 0;
}
```

проблема заключается в том , что не могу отсортировать в самом конце по возрастанию , первые n_n - n элементов
[image]

по идее должно было выводить 3;4;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;

Answer (score 2):

Я расскажу в общем случае, ну, а вы уж свои границы для сортировки подставьте сами.

Итак, `qsort` никто не отменял, даже вы им пытаетесь пользоваться - тогда почему бы не воспользоваться им нормально? просто написав нормальный компаратор, решающий нашу задачу!

```
int trick_comp(const void* a_, const void* b_)
{
    int a = *(int*)a_, b = *(int*)b_;
    if (a && b == 0) return -1;
    if (b && a == 0) return  1;
    return (a < b) ? -1 : (a > b) ? 1 : 0;
}

void trick_sort(int * a, int N)
{
    qsort(a,N,sizeof(int),trick_comp);
}
```

Вот и все.

Полный код можно посмотреть здесь - https://ideone.com/bMGttH

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: Может эффективней будет за один проход переместить все нули в конец, а потом отсортировать  уже более короткий масив?

Comment: @avp Вероятно, быстрее, но явно не так кратко запишется :)

Comment: @knwsrw Если ответ устроил - слева от него есть птичка, которую можно нажать (это и есть спасибо здесь, на ruSO :))

Answer (score 0):

значение `sum` не определено вначале, но затем вы хорошо с ним складываете

и почему тогда уж не `sum += a[i]`?

```
    for (i=0 ;i<N ;i++){  
        sum = sum + a[i];
    }
```

если вы отсортировали массив и вам нужно нули в конец переместить, то почему бы ни

1. подсчитать кол-во 0 (M)
2. переместить поэлементно все элементы с `pos = M..nn-1` до `pos = 0..nn-1-M`
3. остальное заполнить нулями от `pos = nn-1-M` до `pos = nn-1`

   ```
    for (j=0;j<N;j++){ 
            for (  i=0; i< N ; i++){ 
                        if (a[i]<a[i+1])
                        {
                            temp=a[i];
                            a[i]=a[i+1];
                            a[i+1]=temp;
                        }
            }
        }
   ```